# avoid initializing list with data

Tags: c#, forms, list

So, I have two forms. The form1 has a button to open the form2. In the form2 I have a list of elements that I fill with elements I create in the form2. My problem is, when I close my form2 and reopen it, my list is empty. I know that is because Im initializing my list again (`ListaComida = new List<Comida>();)`, so I get my data erased but I dont see how to solve this.

My code

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form

{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
}


    private void addDia_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string dia = (DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
        TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(dia);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
    }

    private void AddComida_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormAddComida addComida = new FormAddComida();
        DialogResult resultaod = addComida.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Form2

```
public partial class FormAddComida : Form
    {
        public List<Comida> ListaComida;

        public FormAddComida()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListaComida = new List<Comida>();

        }

        private void addComidaAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Comida comidaAdicionada = new Comida(tbNome.Text,
                Convert.ToInt32(tbCalorias.Text),
                Convert.ToInt32(tbHidratos.Text),
                Convert.ToInt32(tbProteinas.Text),
                Convert.ToInt32(tbGorduras.Text)
                );

            ListaComida.Add(comidaAdicionada);
            RefreshListaComida();

        }

        private void RefreshListaComida()
        {

            lbListaComida.Items.Clear();
            lbListaComida.Items.AddRange(ListaComida.ToArray());

        }

        private void AddComidaCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Nelson, you don't want to loose the Listacomida object in form2 even if you close the form? that's it ?

Comment: yeap, I want to have the items in my list (and listbox) when I reopen my form2

Comment: i'm creating an example for you, i'll post in few minutes.

Comment: You can keep data with Form1 which is passed to Form2 whenever you open it. The modified list can be stored back with Form1. There can be other choices:
1. Persist data in file system.
2. Persist data in database.

Comment: In my example in persisting into memory, it's an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MemoryCache, even if you close your form your List will stay in Memory and you can retrieve by the Key. But if you need to save this data permanently (or long time running the app )i recommend you store in a DB.

```
    using System.Runtime.Caching;

    private ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;

    public class Food
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }
    }

    public void AddFood()
    {
        FoodList.Add(new Food { Name = "Pizza", Price = 10 });
        FoodList.Add(new Food { Name = "Fries", Price = 5 });

        cache.Add("UserCacheFood", FoodList, DateTimeOffset.MaxValue);
    }

    public List<Food> ReturnListFromCache()
    {
        return (List<Food>)cache.Get("UserCacheFood");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddFood();
        var result = ReturnListFromCache();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ret2 = ReturnListFromCache();
    }
```

Comment: hmm I see. So ill probably just use entity framework so store the data, its safer and easier I guess. Thank you !

Comment: Really depends, but memorycache sometimes it's a good option as well, if you need the data inside the application and don't need to go to DB several times. abraço ::)

Comment: by the way.. take a look in Dapper instead EntityFramework :)

Comment: will do. obrigado :)